Local Group Policy firewall rules not listed in GPO firewall
I have 100+ rules defined as per LGP. I can see all these rules both in Local Windows Firewall in RO mode as well as in HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\WindowsFirewall\FirewallRules. I also can see them via
Get-NetFirewallRule -Direction Outbound -Enabled True -Action Allow -PolicyStore ActiveStore | Select DisplayName
However they are not displayed in LGPO Firewall applet. As of today for unknown reasons they are not present. I have permissions to the aforementioned keys in the registry so it is not R/W issue, I can add new entries and they are added to registry and are displayed in the applet but old ones still invisible.
Exporting policy exports empty rule list. I can export a plain text list but it is not-reimportable.
Any idea how can I fix the rules storage without manual work? There is a LOT of rules.
